# Finite groups with small God's numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-groups, big-list, word-problem

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S$ be generating set it. Now given all words with alphabet $S$, then there exists a minimum word length $N(S,G)$ such that all group elements are represented by a word of length $\le N(S,G)$. A famous example is the group of Rubik's Cube where the answer is known to be 26 (if $S$ is the set of all quarter twists) and this is known as God's number.

Where can I find more example of this kind, i.e. groups where $|S|$ and $N(S,G)$ are know (or there is at least some bound) and we have that $|S|,N(S,G)\ll |G|$?

More generally, can we expect that for most groups we can find some generating set $S$ such that $|S|,N(S,G)\ll |G|$?

Comment: Isn't that the diameter of the Cayley graph?

Comment: I can imagine an asymptotic meaning, but how do I decide for a *single* group $G$ and generating set $S$ whether $\lvert S\rvert, N(S, G) \ll \lvert G\rvert$ is true?

Comment: Computing the quantity $N(S,G)$ is hard in general. The [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X871508DD808EB487) package may be useful for your purpose.

Comment: One example that comes to mind are the Coxeter groups. For example for $G=S_n$ with S=the neighbour-transpositions the length of the longest element (the permutation $(1,n)(2,n-1)...$) is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=O(n^2)$, but the order of the group is of course $n! \gg n^2$

Comment: Intuitively I would say that you will find such a set $S$ for most groups, yes. You might be interested in this conjecture here ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter_(group_theory) ), stating that $N(S,G)$ remains small no matter what set $S$ you take, at least as long as $G$ is simple.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the fundamental questions in the theory of groups known as the *width problem*.

One of the best (general) references devoted to this problem is the book [Words: Notes on Verbal Width in Groups](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/words-notes-verbal-width-groups?format=PB) by Dan Segal.

Yet another good reference is the paper [Width questions for finite simple groups](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~mwl/liebeck_final.pdf) by Martin Liebeck.

A well-known conjecture due to **Babai** states that there must exists a constant $c$ such that $N(S,G)<(\log|G|)^c$ for all non-abelian finite simple groups $G$ and generating sets $S$.

L. Babai and A. Seress, On the diameter of permutation groups, *European J. Combin.* **13** (1992), 231–243.

Comment: I don't think this is width, as far as I remember, width is for specific word. I think it is the diameter of the Cayley graph,

Comment: @YiftachBarnea The width of a group $G$ with respect to a generating set $S$ is the same as the diameter of Cayley graph $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S)$, that is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that every element of $G$ is the product of at most $k$ elements of $S$.

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of this definition.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement $|S|\ll |G|$ looks odd to me as $S$ is a subset of $G$. As to $N(S,G)$ -- well, at least for finite *abelian* groups it [is known](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2966.pdf) to be strictly smaller than the size of the group. In fact, if $G$ is finite abelian of the type $(m_1,\dotsc, m_r)$ with $m_1\mid\dotsb\mid m_r$, then the largest possible value of your $N(S,G)$ as $S$ varies over all generating sets is $(m_1-1)+\dotsb+(m_r-1)$.